# How can I configure AMQ broker on Openshift 4 to ensure messages are consumed by only one pod in a publish-subscriber model?

Tags: java, microservices, openshift, jms, activemq-artemis

I am using Openshift 4 to deploy multiple microservices which are connected via an AMQ broker using a publish-subscribe messaging model. However, when I increase number of pod to 2,  I am running into an issue where all pods are consuming the same message, rather than just one.

Can someone suggest how to configure java code below or the AMQ broker to ensure that messages are consumed by only one pod in a publish-subscriber model? Are there any specific settings I should be aware of or changes I need to make to my configuration? Thank you.

Configuration:

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> jmsListenerContainerPublisherFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                                                         DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setErrorHandler(throwable -> {
        log.info("An error has occurred in the transaction: " + throwable.getMessage());
        log.error("Error: ", throwable);
    });
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return factory;
}
```

Listener:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${queue.dummyObject}",
        containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerPublisherFactory")
public void onConsumePublishedMessage(String message) throws JsonProcessingException {
    DummyObjectDTO dummyObjectDTO = mapper.readValue(message, DummyObjectDTO.class);
    LOG.info(" Received onConsumePublishedMessage message : " + dummyObjectDTO);
}
```

Producer:

```
private  <T> T  sendFeatured(T value, String queue, boolean publish, Selector selector) {
    *
    *
    jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, objectAsJson);
    *
    *
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using ActiveMQ Artemis you can use the shared subscription functionality introduced in JMS 2. When configuring your `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` use [`setSubscriptionShared`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html#setSubscriptionShared(boolean)):

```java
factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);
return factory;
```

Then on your listener you can set the subscription name, e.g.:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "${queue.dummyObject}",
             subscription = "mySubscriptionName",
             containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerPublisherFactory")
```

Each *set* of subscribers will need to use a unique subscription name so that only one of them receives the message rather than all of them.

Comment: Many Thanks Justin, you saved a life.
Because the factory has no method such a setSubscriptionName,  I set it in the listener annotation like below;
```
  @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.dummyObject}",
            subscription = "microservice-name",
            containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerPublisherFactory") 
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations for a Pub/Sub topic do not match It's ise case or capabilities.

If want only a single receiver to process a message then you should be using a **queue** and **a** command, not events.

When using events and Pub/Sub (topics) with multiple subscribers doing the same task, then you have to make sure that the event processing is idempotent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I want to receive the same message in every microservice, but not every pod(replica). I have 4 microservices, one of them is publisher, other three are consumer. So these 3 microservices should receive the message. However every consumer microservice has min 2 replicas, just one of them should receive the message. Is this still wrong?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can have multiple subscribers (as many as you want), you have to make sure that the operation carried out upon receiving the event is idempotent. If the event is "pay Bill $500" and 3 subscribers give me $500, I'll be happy but you won't be. An idempotent Event needs something that identifies the event so you can be sure that it is done only once. VERY simple example: PaymentEvent {currentBalance:2000,payment:500}, the first subscriber sees that balance and makes the payment, the others see currentBalance==1500 and do nothing.